# How can i deploy angular app as https://USERNAME.github.io on Github Pages

Tags: angular, git, deployment, configuration, github-pages

I am trying to create a portfolio with angular and deploying it on my user github page (username.github.io), but I'm not being able to make it work...

Steps I'm doing:
1- Created a repository called "username.github.io" on my github root;
2- ng new portfolio --dir=.  (So the project will be created on the "username.github.io folder");
3- Changing "angular.json" file so the outputPath is "dist/" only, removing the work portfolio from it;
4- ng build --base-href=https://username.github.io/;
5- ngh;
6- Commit and push changes to master;

No error messages show up, but then when i try to reach the url "username.github.io" it shows up error 404.

I've tried a bunch of different configurations and each time a different thing happens. On github my repo is configurated to use the master branch (this is the default configuration and can't be changed for user pages).

EDIT:

You can check you it on: https://arthurobdfv.github.io/ 
And the repo: https://github.com/Arthurobdfv/arthurobdfv.github.io

Comment: there is no *dist* folder - remove it from .gitignore

Comment: also, it should be done another way, as I remember: please read docs(https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages); check the setting a for a project - it would say where it would be published. Also, the final URL should be something like https://arthurobdfv.github.io/arthurobdfv.github.io

Comment: You `master` branch seems to contain only source code. The HTML to be published is in branch `gh-pages`. So verify that you've configured branch `gh-pages` to be published and push the branch.

Comment: @andriishupta I was trying to do it useing "docs/" folder this time, but if you look again i've build with dist this time.

Comment: @phd I believe the ngh command makes all thing it needs on gh-pages branch, all tutorials i've seen no one make changes on that branch

Comment: @ArthuroVerissimo No problem but did you configure the repository at Github to publish the branch `gh-pages` and not `master`? Look at https://github.com/Arthurobdfv/arthurobdfv.github.io/settings, section `GitHub Pages`.

Comment: @phd On the settings page it says "User pages must be built from the master branch."

Comment: Change `master` to `gh-pages` and push something new to `gh-pages`.

Comment: @phd As i could see, there is a difference between user pages and project pages, github doesn't allow me to change the branch i'm using for the source

Comment: Ah, yes, see [the docs](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#publishing-sources-for-github-pages-sites): "*The default publishing source for user and organization sites is the master branch. If the repository for your user or organization site has a master branch, your site will publish automatically from that branch. You cannot choose a different publishing source for user or organization sites.*" So you have to configure angular to generate HTML in `master` and publish `master`.

Comment: You mean, by changing angular.json and remove the "dist" from output?

Comment: Ok, got it working, but something weird happened, it seems that the ngh command ovewritten the source files from my project and now how can i make changes on my project if its all gone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of this wonderful community I got it working by addind the "branch" option on the ngh command!!!

For users and organization pages, differently from a project page, github looks for the compiled and built files on the master branch, and the ngh command makes the build available on the "gh-pages" branch by default.